# Changing Silverlight Datagrid columns display index always throws argument out of range exception

Tags: silverlight-4.0, datagrid

I have a datagrid in a view that has its items source bound to an observable collection in my viewmodel.  This works fine.  I have defined the columns and bindings for the datagrid in the views xaml. All of the columns have a unique name that matches the database column name that they represent.

I have created a user control that contains all of the filters for the datagrid.  The user control has a command that the view model binds to that provides the view model with all of the parameters that it needs to call a ria service and populate the observable collection that is bound to the datagrids items source. This works fine.

I have a service that has a reference to the datagrid and subscribes to one of the filter user control's events. When the event fires the service changes the column headers and then reorders the columns using the columns display index, it then collapses columns that are no longer relevant.

All of this works, except the changing of the display index.  Eveytime that I change one of the display index values I get an out of range exception. I have looked at the indexes before leaving the method and they are valid. I have tried waiting till after the databinding has occured and it made no difference.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.    Here is the stacktrace:

> at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[]
>   cvData)    at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(DependencyObject obj,
>   String name)    at System.Windows.UIElement.UpdateLayout()

Comment: Found a temporary fix, would still like to know if anyone knows the proper solution.  I ended up having to create my own datagrid, create an event that the service could call and then override the arrange method and fire the event.  Since arrange gets called multiple times I had to put a property in the service that checks if it has been called before and if so skips the loop that sets up the columns.